# Return Create Object ID Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest

I have a view that extends CreateAPIView. I'd like the ID of the created object included somewhere in the response. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your serializer look like? Does it have the 'id' in the fields to be included?

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include

The serializer decides what the object returned looks like in the API